# git-clean with GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython, git-clean

Is there any way to do something like `git clean -d -x -f` using GitPython?

I need to reset working directories and want to get rid of all unversioned files without deleting the whole folder (except for `.git`) and checking out again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can work around by using the `git` command directly, from gitpython

```
git = repo.git
git.clean('-xdf')
```